Azure SQL returning old name for a database I renamed
I have a database named: sql-MyProj-dev-e2-001.database.windows.net
I need to rename it to remove the e2 (the part in bold).
I have the SQL Below:
select name 
from sys.databases 
where name like '%-e2-%' and name like '%-MyProj-%' 

My deployment, running as the Microsoft Entra Admin, executes a powershell script that runs the SQL with ExecuteScalar which returns my database name.  Then I use an alter statement to rename the database. This worked as expected.
Next I run that exact SQL in SSMS, running as myself, and no rows are returned. That is to be expected because the name no longer contians e2.
However, if I run my deployment again it finds the database with the e2 in the name.
My script has these lines:
$SqlConnection.Open()
$theName = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
write-host "Retrieved Value: $theName"
$SqlConnection.Close()

That line that writes out the retrived value show this:
sql-MyProj-dev-e2-001.database.windows.net
In SMSM I run this:
select name 
from sys.databases 

Which returns two rows (and the -e2- names database is not there):
master
sql-MyProj-dev-001.database.windows.net

With SSMS, running as me, I don't see the old database name (with the -e2-), but I do see it when powershell runs the command as the Microsoft Entra Admin.
When running as Microsoft Entra Admin, does sys.databases return the renamed (or deleted) databases? Is there a field I can restrict to that only returns the active databases?

This question might be better suited to https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

"However, if I run my deployment again it finds the database with the e2 in the name." - What do you mean by deployment? What are you using to deploy this database?
